# Particules speed in ideal gasses

Tags: ideal-gas

According to Graham's law, we can calculate de average speed of gasses by using the formula

$$v^2=\frac{3RT}{M}$$

I tried to use this [simulation](https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/gas-properties/latest/gas-properties_en.html) and got these data by keeping same particles amount and increasing the temperature(average speed(m/s) - temperatura(°C)):

| T in C | V in m/s |
| --- | --- |
| 27 | 454 |
| 50 | 480 |
| 90 | 510 |
| 130 | 530 |
| 225 | 590 |
| 350 | 660 |
| 425 | 710 |
| 500 | 740 |

But, shouldn't be the speed ($v$) a square function of the temperature? ($T=\frac{Mv^2}{3R}$ ) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The shoe is on the other foot (the square is on the other quantity), and you should use the Kelvin scale. Using the Celsius scale, RT will not be proportional to the kinetic energy of particles (just try below freezing to convince yourself).

Comment: You are confused about the equations. Your first equation is a function of temperature and the second is a function of v squared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

| T in K | $V^2$ in $\pu{m2 s-2}$ |
| --- | --- |
| 300 | 206116 |
| 323 | 230400 |
| 363 | 260100 |
| 403 | 280900 |
| 498 | 348100 |
| 623 | 435600 |
| 698 | 504100 |
| 773 | 547600 |

These are proportional.